# How to count and display duplicate entries in MySQL on PHP website

Tags: php, mysql

I'd like to know how I can count and display duplicate rows on my PHP website. Let's assume that my website allows one to submit a name. How do I then display these names on my website? Let's say that the names in the database are:

```
John
Derrick
Billy
Jason
Wesley
Billy
John
Billy
```

I'd then like the website to display the following:

```
John: 2
Derrick: 1
Billy: 3
Jason: 1
Wesley: 1
```

How can I achieve this sort of structure?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Sounds like just a `mysql` question.

Comment: I don't think that is even special to `mysql`, more like general `sql`. But I think some self-initiative reading examples for all the different parts of the task is a good start. Basically two simple things are required: 1) querying a database in PHP and displaying the result, 2) performing a database query with `grouped by`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can make this:

`select name, count(*) from your_table group by name`

And that would return something like this:

`name | count
John | 2`

If you want the name and the count, you can make a concat

`select concat(name, ": ", count(*)) from your_table group by name`

And it would return something like this:

`name
John: 2`

(just one column)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$ps=$db->prepare("SELECT column_name, count(*) as nb FROM table_name GROUP BY column_name");
$ps->execute()
while($data=$ps->fetch()){
echo $data['column_name'].':'.$data['nb'].'<br/>';
}

?>
```

$db is the connection instance